# Bootstrap alerts within a modal bootstrap using laravel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, laravel, laravel-5

im new in bootstrap modal's. 
how could show the variable $ errors within the modal, after making the validation with laravel 5.2?
something more like this:
[image]

in modal i have:

```
<!--- Register Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Register" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Registro</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">


       <form role="form" actior="{{ route('register') }}" method='post' >

              <label>  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Nombre: </label>
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" name='name' placeholder="ingresa tu nombre">
                </div>
                </label>
                <label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Apellido: </label>
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" name='lastname' placeholder="ingresa tu apellido">
                </div>
                </label>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Correo electronico: </label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="pwd">Contraseña:</label>
                 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="ingrese la contraseña">
            </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                 <label >Confirmar contraseña:</label>
                 <input type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="ingrese nuevamente la contraseña">
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}"> <!---seguridad -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="send(event)"  data-dismiss="modal" id='Submit'>Registro</button>

    </form>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

the variables sent them with jquery using this code:

```
function send(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{{route('register')}}",
    data: {name: $('#name').val(), lastname: $('#lastname').val(), email:   $('#email').val(), password: $('#password').val(),   _token:'{{Session::token()}}'} 
 });
  $('#header').load();
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#other-validation-approaches), try to validate manually your form, and then attach errors to the response ?

In JS :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{{route('register')}}",
    data: {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
        email:   $('#email').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
        _token:'{{Session::token()}}' // Bad practice to mix Js and PHP
    },
    success: function(res) {
        if (res.error) {
            // Add error in your modal, for example :
            $('#Register').prepend(data.error);
        }
        else {
            // Close your modal
            $('#Register').modal('hide');
        }
    }
});
```

In your Laravel controller :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

    // Your form rules, for example :
    'name' => 'required|string|max:32',
    'lastname' => 'required|string|max:32',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|alpha_num',
]);

if ($validator->fails())
    return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()->first()]);
```

For the Js part, you should have a look to the [jQuery .serialize() method](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: that you recommend me to correct bad practice to mix with php js

Comment: For the Session::token(), you could add a data attribute in your HTML view, and then accessing it via query selector in Js. For example `<form id="my-form" data-token="{{ Session::token() }}"> ...` with a `$('#my-form').attr('data-token');`